# prove that $z=x^{2}+y$ is a cyclic identity:

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

An equation $f(x,y,z) = 0$ is said to be a cyclic identity if
$$\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \right) \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \right) \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right) = -1.$$

I have been trying to figure out how to prove $f(x,y,z)=x^{2}+y-z = 0$ is a cyclic identity and even wrote down all the possible derivatives of the equations $z=x^{2}+y$ and $x=\sqrt{z-y}$ and $y=z-x^{2}$

However, I can not find anything to cancel out the x's and square root values. Can someone please help me work through this, I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: I think that first you have to tell us what you mean by the phrase, "cyclic identity". It's not a phrase I've come across in $50$ years of doing Mathematics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP shows no interest in engaging with the community.

Comment: @gerry-myerson this was my first post so i do not know how fast people respond or how to use this site. I put chemistry because it came up in my chemistry class but they did state it was a calculus question. cyclic identity just meant that when you take the partial derivatives, they should multiply to -1.

Comment: @SKeshavarz Welcome to Math.Stackexchange! I must admit that I also never heard about the term of cyclic identity and I don't understand the formulation "when you take the partial derivatives, they should multiply to -1". Perhaps it's a term well known in chemistry. Could you provide a more detailed definition or a share link to some related materials. (Can the definition be found on Wikipedia?)

Comment: Welcome back. Here are some things you can do: Edit your question to include a clear and unambiguous explanation of what you mean by "cyclic identity". If you found the answer by user @Matteo to be useful, you can "upvote" it by clicking on the up-arrow next to it (actually, I'm not sure you can do that, you may need to have acquired some points on this website first). If that answer completely answers your question, you can "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it. If that answer doesn't completely answer your question, you can leave a comment explaining what more you still need.

Comment: [Wikipedia gives proofs that this identity is "always" true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule#Derivation).  So, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I follow this definition of cyclic identity:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule

Write $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y-z = 0$. Note for example that
$$x = \pm \sqrt{z-y}.$$
Compute
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = \frac{ - \text{sign}(x)}{2 \sqrt{z-y}}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = 1, \, \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2x.$$
Now multiply all partial derivatives, and find
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\text{sign}(x) \frac{x}{\sqrt{z-y}} = -\text{sign}(x) \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} = -\text{sign}(x) \frac{x}{|x|} = -\text{sign}(x) \text{sign}(x) = -1.$$

Comment: Perhaps it's simpler to use implicit differentiation to get ${\partial x\over\partial y}$; $2x{\partial x\over\partial y}+1=0$, so ${\partial x\over\partial y}=-1/(2x)$.